# DateTime.Parse fails for today (01 mar 2012)! o_0

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Today I got a really strange problem.

Try to execute this C# code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string yesterdayString = (DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).ToString("R");
        string nowString = DateTime.Now.ToString("R");

        DateTime.Parse(yesterdayString);
        DateTime.Parse(nowString);

        DateTime.Parse("Wed, 29 Feb 2012 18:05:49 GMT"); // this is what i have in yesterdayString
        DateTime.Parse("Thu, 01 Mar 2012 18:05:40 GMT"); // this is what i have in nowString
    }
}
```

Of course you will get the problem just for today. I've added the last two commands to let you know what the problem is.
Tomorrow and throughout the month of March DateTime.Parse will throw a FormatException (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.)

Why?

Comment: This code works when I run it through Linqpad.

Comment: Works fine for me on .NET 4.0, FWIW.

Comment: Tested it with different CultureInfos, but can't reproduce.

Comment: Are you running this on Azure by any chance? :) (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/03/01/windows-azure-service-disruption-update.aspx)

Comment: It compiles fine for me. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Worked for me also, what version of .Net are you using?

Comment: http://rextester.com/EUA48977 <<< see for yourself (click Run it)

Comment: It fails in every Spanish culture (via `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)`) as well as a few others for me.  So what culture are you running in?

Comment: I think i use italian culture.. i will verify as soon as I can.. maybe it is a problem on Latin cultures.

Comment: ok.. i verified that the problem is related to the current culture;
try to add the follow line as the first command:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you found a bug.  This should work:

```
// 
var spanish = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es");
var date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("R", spanish), spanish);
```

or for Italian it still throws...

```
var italian = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it");
var date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("R", italian), italian);
```

Comment: It seems that the datetime parser do not like the italian and spanish March month.. your solution do not works for me.. i will give me a self solution =D .. thanks anyway.

ps..
i can't give me an answer.. so i give you an hint:
            DateTime.Parse(nowString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));

Comment: @user846168:  It wasn't meant to be a solution but rather a _too-big-for-a-comment_ answer.  That's why I marked it as a CW.

Answer (score 2):

This is confirmed to be a bug.

If you need more info on this topic, please look at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/822536/datetime-parse-result-in-exception-when-the-format-is-rfc1123-pattern-and-locale-is-a-latin-one

Comment: This is it, I had the same problem today. Probably its because in spanish, March = Marzo, so with RFC1123 standard .net cannot resolve "Mar" when you are at "es" locale and they dont know how to make a workaround for this bug, so they closed it as "won't fix" (*facepalm*)