# DateTime.Parse issue on 1st of March 2017

Tags: c#, datetime, mono

I'm working with Xamarin (mainly forms) and a few days ago I discovered that issue.

When i call a webservice I look on response's header for Date field and try to parse it.

That works fine until 28th of February:

```
DateTime dt_OK = DateTime.Parse("Tue, 28 Feb 2017 11:07:06 GMT");
```

But, starting from 01 of March:

```
DateTime dt_KO = DateTime.Parse("Wed, 01 Mar 2017 11:07:06 GMT");
```

I get: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". But it is a valid datetime! 01 March 2017 was a wednesday...

ok, I know that exit ParseExact (which I tried and worked) but how about .Parse()?

```
DateTime dt_always_ok = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFromHeader, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

All days of march will not be recognized and parsed.. it restarts to work from April 01.

Anyone else faced that behaviour?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture` exactly? It _might_ have `ddd, d ...` instead of `ddd, dd ...` as a standard date and time format.

Comment: CurrentCulture:

Comment: CurrentCulture: {it-IT} and DateTimeFormatInfo is:
 FullDateTimePattern: "dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
 LongDatePattern: "dddd d MMMM yyyy"
 LongTimePattern: "HH:mm:ss"
 MonthDayPattern: "d MMMM"
 RFC1123Pattern: "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"
 ShortDatePattern: "dd/MM/yyyy"
 ShortTimePattern: "HH:mm"
 SortableDateTimePattern: "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"
 UniversalSortableDateTimePattern: "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
 YearMonthPattern: "MMMM yyyy"  ...but why it worked until 28th Feb starting from September 2016? Wed, 01 Feb 2017 was correctly recognized...

Comment: What is the month abbreviation for March in Italian? I guess it is not *Mar*. There is your problem.

Comment: For me it works fine with your string and {it-IT} culture, no errors.

Comment: @PatrickHofman for some reason DateTime.Parse can parse such string correctly with any culture I tried, even with russian culture which does not have latin letters at all in month names.

Comment: "Mar" sounds a lot like "martedì", the name of Tuesday in Italian.  Parsing English date formats with an it-IT culture selection sounds pretty unwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems reproducible only for `Mono mcs` compiler, not for `.Net` framework.

In that case, it looks like a [known](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/822536/datetime-parse-result-in-exception-when-the-format-is-rfc1123-pattern-and-locale-is-a-latin-one#) **bug**, because even (!)

```
DateTime dt_KO = DateTime.Parse("01 Mar 2017",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

produces the following error

```
System.FormatException: Giorno della settimana non corretto. Stringa non riconosciuta come DateTime valido.
```

that means "*String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect*", while `"Mar"` is the correct `"MMM"` format for the month.

It looks like they didn't consider that a month and a day could have the same abbreviation in the current Italian language.

A possible workaround for DateTime.Parse would be

```
DateTime dt_KO = DateTime.Parse("Wed, 01 Mar 2017 11:07:06 GMT",
                                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521016/datetime-parse-fails-for-today-01-mar-2012-o-0)

Answer (score 3):

I think [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597723/datetime-parse-issue-on-1st-of-march-2017#comment72326955_42597723) is on the right way. Looks like your "Mar" is *not* parsed in `Parse` method as an abbreviate month name of the [marzo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marzo) which is March in Italian. It try to parse it as an abbreviate day name of the [martedi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marted%C3%AC) instead which is tuesday in Italian. And since you try to parse two different abbreviate day names in your string, you get an exception.

But still, it is too weird to parse your english month and day names with an italian culture. Use a *english-based* culture instead like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture). And if you have a custom format, you might wanna choose [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) or [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact) methods to prevent this kind of ambiguous situations.

Comment: But then why this `DateTime.Parse("Wed, 01 Mar 2017 11:07:06 GMT", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT"));` and even this `DateTime.Parse("Wed, 01 Mar 2017 11:07:06 GMT", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"));` work fine?

Comment: @Evk Because this is a standard date and time format called [RFC1123Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.rfc1123pattern) which will be use "r" or "R" in `ToString` method. It says: "The RFC1123 pattern reflects a defined standard, and the property is read-only. _Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the culture_. The custom format string is `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT`". I think this applies for parsing operation as well.

Comment: Ok, so OP uses it-IT culture, why it does not work for him then? Your first paragraph and your comment seems to contradict each other, not?

Comment: @Evk As I said, this `it-IT` culture is _not_ recognize this string with `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT` format but `ddd, dd ddd yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT` instead with two different abbreviate day name. Yes, _that_ `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT` format _is_ culture invariant, but this string, for `it-IT` culture, is **not** in `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT` format at all.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But I'm asking why when I myself on my machine run this: `DateTime.Parse("Wed, 01 Mar 2017 11:07:06 GMT", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT"));` I have **no** error? Same string, same culture (it-IT) but no error.

Comment: Maybe because of different .Net Framework versions? It parses on my VS but it throws exception on my LINQPad on the same machine. I'm not sure, honestly..

Comment: Ok thanks. Not that it matters much, just was curious what is really in play here.